# WideVine Certification DRM problem on Android phone

Tags: android, drm, widevine, oppo

I have a WideVine Certification problem with my android phone.
I have a Oppo Find X2 Pro where my security level is L3, but it should be L1. The problem is that L3 forces all streaming Apps like Netflix and Hbo Max to stream in max 480p SD resolution. I tried everything, even found a fix from this site (https://www.droidwin.com/widevine-l1-downgraded-to-l3-on-oppo-how-to-fix/) but I have a problem with the installation. Here are the photos for more Information: [DRM Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqKil.jpg) [downloaded APK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDuLX.jpg)
[[installation error] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuwxB.jpg)] I dont even know which app on my phone I should uninstall to force the apk to install

I tried to install the APK fix, but I always get the message that the package conflicts with an existing package